# Turbo build returns "error hashing package files: git error"

Tags: git, turborepo

I have a project that uses pnpm and turbo build.
I just ran into a strange issue. I have a file (`compSelect copy.tsx`) that I deleted. When I then run `turbo build`, I get:

```
run failed: error hashing package files: git error: 'git status' in /Users/... had a parse error git error: failed to parse git-status:  copy.tsx
```

If I delete the `.git` folder, I can build with turbo, so it's indeed somehow related to data stored in that `.git` folder. But what and where?

Is there a solution/fix/workaround?

Comment: Is the file tracked in git (``git add copy.tsx``)?

Comment: @JosephWorks If I delete the file or change it in any way, then it appears in `git status`. Building with turbo then fails. If I undelete it, or revert changes, then turbo builds just fine.

Comment: If the file isn't useful, remove it and commit your changes by going to the root of your project and typing ``git add . && git commit -m "Fixed turbo build"``, if the file is necessary, do the above without removing the file.

Comment: @JosephWorks thanks, that helped. Turbo was able to build after adding and committing, however, now I have a commit that I never intended to have. Not a big deal.

Comment: I'm glad this helped! I submitted an answer, so if you could mark that as the solution, I would appreciate that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `copy.tsx` was not being tracked by git, so `git status` was throwing a warning that the build was not able to parse.

To fix the issue, add the file using `git add copy.tsx` and then commit your changes.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely because you have a space in a filename that was created when your OS renamed something to avoid overwriting an existing file.

`Something.tsx` => `Something copy.tsx`, which Turbo is blowing up on and incorrectly reporting as `copy.tsx`

I smell a regex...